# Template rendering engine on Raspberry Pi

Tags: webkit, raspberry-pi, phantomjs, python-imaging-library, thermal-printer

I have a project in which I am using a Raspberry Pi to print ticket to a thermal printer. 
It is pretty much the same principle as in [this video](http://youtu.be/B_bytm9_P4w).

Tickets are generated from templates that may include text and images. Both text and images are dynamic, for example I may want to print the current time. I receive the template as a .psd from a designer and the thermal printer takes bitmap data. The Raspberry Pi communicates to the printer with a python library. Everything must be done locally as cloud access is not guaranteed. Performance is important.

I investigated several options:

1. Latex + ImageMagick
2. Webkit + Phantom.js
3. Pillow (Python Imaging Library), especially the module ImageDraw

The first option is not quite satisfying because Latex generates a pdf file and then ImageMagick is very slow to convert it to a .png.

The second option is seducing but if I am not mistaken, I would need to start a server locally.

The third option would be great because it will be pure python, but requires to build a basic typesetting system on top of PIL.

Has anyone been confronted to a similar problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would load a .psd into a webpage to render it in PhantomJS. I'm not clear in how you would reproduce the .psd in those 3 options. You can run your PhantomJS script on demand. No need to run a PhantomJS server instance.

Comment: I was a little bit elusive on that step. Actually I need to integrate the design of the template, either in html/css, or latex, or some custom typesetting if using PIL.